# (Latin) Abbrevation for 'apropos' / 'regarding' / 'with respect to'

Tags: abbreviations, latin

I am looking for a convenient abbreviation for the construction of 'with respect to' or 'regarding' or 'apropos'. I used to write "A with respect to B" as "A cf. B" but this is not really correct. Is there a better or proper abbreviation for this ?

Comment: The abbreviation *w.r.t.* or *wrt* is very common, at least in mathematics and technical literature. I use it frequently.

Comment: If you use such extremely vague ways of relating one thing to another so habitually as to require an abbreviation, then that habit is the problem to be solved—not the lack of “a convenient abbreviation.”

Answer (score 1):

"A with respect to B" --> "A wrt. B"

"Regarding A" --> "Re: A"

Apropos doesn't have a convenient abbreviation as far as I'm aware of as it is a relatively uncommon word.

Answer (score 0):

[WRT](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/With+respect+to):

> - With Regard To
> - With Reference To

The Free Dictionary

[WRT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acronyms:_W):

> - – "With respect to", especially in fields such as Mathematics. (Wikipedia)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wrt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwrt%3B%2Cc0) : ***WRT, w.r.t. wrt***, you can see here many usage examples during the last decades.

Answer (score 0):

*Vis-à-vis* is a French phrase meaning "with regard to."  Like many Latin phrases, it has become so popular in English that it is no longer italicized in common usage.

See also [What is the correct usage of “vis-à-vis”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10010/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-vis-%C3%A0-vis)